# ForEach loop stops when a returned valus is $null

Tags: powershell

The foraech loop breaks if a certain service is not present on the server on one of the servers in the to do list

Expect a csv file containing the OpenSSH services if the Windows Optional Feature OpenSSH server and OpenSSH client is installed with the corresponding server name

csv file is filled up to the first server where the service does not exist. The server on which the service does not exist is still written to the csv file with the else statement, but then the foreach loop hangs and does not go futher to the next server.

output:

[image]

```
#check of OpenSSH service zijn geïnstalleerd

$Servers = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\2019servers.txt
$column_number = 4

ForEach ($Server in $Servers) {
    $Services = (Get-Service -Name "SSH*" -ComputerName $server | Select-Object -Property Name,StartType,status,displayname,machinename)
    If (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Services)))
    {
    Write-Host $Server
    $Services | Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\2019_openssh_services.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append -Force
    }
    else
    {
    Write-Host "$Server no openssh services"
    Add-Content -Path c:\temp\2019_openssh_services.csv -Value "$(","*$column_number)$Server"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: With `$Services = (Get-Service -Name ....` you will recieve an **object**, an **array of objects** or nothing at all (`$null)`, so you should not treat it as a string in the if that follows. Change that to `if (@($Services).Count)`. Also I would suggest capturing all output from the loop in a variable and after the loop has finished export that to the output csv file in one go instead of appending each time.

Comment: Use Import-Csv instead of Get-Content.  Get-Content is not splitting the CSV rows into columns.

Comment: @jdweng Get-content is just a bunch of servers it gets from a txt file, each server is on one line. So i don't see the benefits from a csv file above a txt file

Comment: Get-Content does not split the rows into columns.  You have : $column_number = 4

Comment: Thanks all for helping.
I have it working now.

Comment: i captured all output from the loop in a variable and after the loop has finished export that to the output csv file so as _theo advised